# Mysql query backup. What would be considered best practices?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been doing some googling but I don't know if my search terms could be better.

I am making a database that will keep customer information. I have a few reps that will have access to that data using the php website front end and I would like to put something in place to allow me to undo a mistake that could occur.

I initially thought to make a trigger for all update and/or insert queries in which it would save the query used and would make a backup of the contents of the table before the query was executed.

I wasn't sure if that would be considered best practice or if there was a better option I could be overlooking.

I would appreciate any input on if this route seems best or should I be looking towards a different option. 
Thanks!

Comment: I hear that Microsoft was *this close* to putting an *Oops!* button next to the *Del* button.

Comment: http://www.jasny.net/articles/versioning-mysql-data/

Comment: JaredFarrish offtopic gmail has this feature, what it does is set a delay before it actually sends your email so if you like you can undo the action

@zamnuts thanks for this! this is exactly what I was planning to do but this saves me a ton of time in figuring the exact parts out he provides some code for implementation and not to mention I like he also allows comments for the revisions too.

I'll give it a try and report back here incase someone finds this page by googling some time in the future.